# How to test recover from error ErrorBoundry case

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-testing-library

Pretty much what the title says.

I have a a test case that looks like this:

```
  it("recovers from error boundry", async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup();
    const ThrowError = () => {
      throw new Error("Test");
    };

    render(
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <ThrowError />
      </ErrorBoundary>
    );

    expect(screen.getByTestId("alert")).toBeInTheDocument();

    await user.click(screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Try again?" }));

    expect(screen.queryByRole("alert")).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  });
```

And an ErrorBoundry which looks like this:

```
class ErrorBoundary extends Component<ErrorBoundryProps, ErrorBoundryState> {
  state = { hasError: false };

  static getDerivedStateFromError() {
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidCatch(error: Error, info: ErrorInfo) {
    // IRL would log to an error reporting serive
    //errorService.log({ error, info });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return (
        <div className="app-error-boundry" role="alert">
          <div className="app-error-boundry__content">
            <h1 className="app-error-boundry__title">Something went wrong.</h1>
            <button
              type="button"
              className="app-error-boundry__btn btn"
              onClick={() => this.setState({ hasError: false })}
            >
              Try again?
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }
}
```

However, in the test the ErrorBoundry is still being found after the button to reset error state is being clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you reset the error state, the `ErrorBoundary` component will render `this.props.children` which is the `ThrowError` component. The problem is this component will **always** throw an error when it renders. So the `ErrorBoundary` will always catch the error, and the error state `hasError` will always be true. There is no chance of recovering from the error.

You should use some conditions to throw the error from your test component.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React from "react";

export class ErrorBoundary extends React.Component {
  state = { hasError: false };

  static getDerivedStateFromError() {
    return { hasError: true };
  }

  componentDidCatch() { }

  render() {
    if (this.state.hasError) {
      return (
        <div role="alert">
          <div>
            <h1>Something went wrong.</h1>
            <button
              type="button"
              onClick={() => this.setState({ hasError: false })}
            >
              Try again?
            </button>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }

    return this.props.children;
  }
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { render, screen, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { ErrorBoundary } from '.';

describe('74115177', () => {
  test('should pass', () => {
    const ThrowError = () => {
      const [count, setCount] = useState(0);
      if (count > 1) {
        throw new Error("Test");
      }
      return <div>
        <p>count: {count}</p>
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>increment</button>
      </div>
    };

    render(
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <ThrowError />
      </ErrorBoundary>
    );

    fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'increment' }))
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole('button', { name: 'increment' }))

    expect(screen.queryByRole("alert")).toBeInTheDocument();
    fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button", { name: "Try again?" }));
    expect(screen.queryByRole("alert")).not.toBeInTheDocument();
  })
})
```